# SSL Error - Alert number 80 - When calling server from client

Tags: node.js, reactjs, ssl, heroku, vercel

I am a newbie in web development, I developed my first basic CRUD app. It works as expected in my local. As a portfolio item, I wanted create an actual website. I bought domain name & SSL certificate etc, deployed my back end and front end etc.  However I am struggling with an issue for the last couple of days. Please see the details below

**Background Info**

- Server: I have a nodejs application on Heroku (example.com). I bought an ssl certificate for my domain (i.e. example.com). I inserted certificate and intermediate certificate in Heroku and linked with my back end.
- Client: I deployed my React & nextjs frontend on Vercel (subdomain.example.com). Vercel is creating its own certificate for subdomain.example.com

My issue is that I am receiving the following error in my website. After I wait couple minutes and refresh the error disappears. If I don't use it for some time again, the error reappears.

```
[Network] FetchError: request to https://example.com/graphql failed, reason: write EPROTO 139801265354624:error:14094438:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 alert internal error:../deps/openssl/openssl/ssl/record/rec_layer_s3.c:1544:SSL alert number 80
```

See below my code for nodejs

```
  const conn = await createConnection({
    type: "postgres",
    url: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    host: process.env.PG_HOST,
    username: process.env.PG_USER,
    password: process.env.PG_PASSWORD,
    port: parseInt(process.env.PORT),
    database: process.env.PG_DATABASE,
    logging: true,
    migrations: [path.join(__dirname, "./migrations/*")],
    entities: [Bank, User, Report],
    ssl: __prod__ ? {rejectUnauthorized: false} : false
  })
  const redisStore = connectRedis(session);
  const redis = new Redis(process.env.REDIS_URL);
  app.set("trust proxy", 1)
  app.use(cors({
    origin: __prod__ ? process.env.CORS_ORIGIN : "http://localhost:3000",
    credentials: true
  }))

  app.use(
    session({
      name: COOKIE_NAME,
      store: new redisStore({
        client: redis,
        disableTouch: true
      }),
      cookie: {
        maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365 * 10, 
        httpOnly: true,
        sameSite: "none",
        secure: __prod__,
        domain: __prod__ ? process.env.DOMAIN : undefined
      } as CookieOptions ,
      saveUninitialized: false,
      secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
      resave: false
    })
  )

  const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
    schema: await buildSchema({
      resolvers: [BankResolver, UserResolver, ReportResolver],
      validate: false
    }),
    context: ({req, res}): MyContext => ({req, res, redis})
  })
  await apolloServer.start()
  apolloServer.applyMiddleware({app, cors: false});
  app.listen(parseInt(process.env.PORT), () => console.log("Server listening on port 4000"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came across "alert number 80" in a different context (a Nagios check_http, where enabling SNI helped).  Anyways, "alert number 80" means "internal_error" (see [RFC 5246 Section 7.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.2)).  It is sent by the TLS server to the TLS client meaning

> An internal error unrelated to the peer or the correctness of the
> protocol (such as a memory allocation failure) makes it impossible to
> continue.  This message is always fatal.

It might help to upgrade Node.js or whatever it uses to implement SSL.