# Mongo Db Atlass and Compass connection

Tags: database, mongodb

I was trying to connect Mongo atlas with compass. While connecting, I got the following error:

> 2269824:error:10000438:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:TLSV1_ALERT_INTERNAL_ERROR:....\third_party\boringssl\src\ssl\tls_record.cc:592:SSL alert number 80

Comment: This might be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75664032/2282634